# No value for argument 'on_delete'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to run some python code, using django, but it is returning that "No value for argument 'on_delete' in constructor call".

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                    related_name="games_first_player")
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                    related_name="games_second_player")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Move(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    by_first_player = models.BooleanField()


game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Following Code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name="games_first_player")
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name="games_second_player")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Move(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    by_first_player = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 3):

`on_delete` is a required argument on a `ForeignKey` field as of Django 2.0.  [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)